# Is $a_n=\ln(n)/\sqrt n$ increasing or deacreasing

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

How do we proving that:
$$\forall n\ge 9 : a_n = \frac{\ln(n)}{\sqrt n}$$ increasing or decreasing

**My methode**
Let :$f(x)=\frac{\ln x}{\sqrt x} $where $ x \ge 9$

$$f'(x)=\frac{\frac{\sqrt x}{x}-\frac{\ln x}{2\sqrt x}}{x}=\frac{1}{x^2}\left({\sqrt{x} - \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{x}\ln x}\right)$$

We have : $$x \ge 9 \implies f'(x) \le 0$$
therefore : $f(x)$ decreasing

Finally: $a_n$ decreasing $\forall n\ge 9$

**My question:**
are another way method ?

> **I appreciate your interest**

Comment: Perhaps you my check/compute the limit of given array...

Comment: I not understand ???

Comment: @Anton The limit of the sequence does not, on its own, tell you that the sequence is monotonically decreasing. For example, the sequence $a_n = \sin^2(n)/n$ is not monotonically decreasing, but it is a sequence of positive numbers that approaches $0$.

Comment: To @BenGrossmann: Thanks for your remark. To Mostafa: your method is correct.

Comment: I don’t think this is really a different method. But note that $a_n$ is increasing/decreasing iff $a_n/2$ is, and $a_n/2 = \log(\sqrt{n})/\sqrt{n}$ by log properties. So it suffices to check whether $\log(x)/x$ is increasing or decreasing. And I think this is a little more intuitively clear.

Comment: @Mostafa Your method is the fastest approach. There are other approaches, but I don't think the other approaches are faster or easier

Comment: @Mostafa If you're interested in a method that avoids calculus, it would be sufficient to show that
$$
\frac{\sqrt{n+1} - \sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n}} > \frac{\ln(n+1) - \ln(n)}{\ln(n)}
$$
for sufficiently large $n$, or equivalently that
$$
\frac{\sqrt{n+1}}{\sqrt{n}} > \frac{\ln(n+1)}{\ln(n)}
$$

Comment: Thank's everyone